# Prove that the application $\psi_a:F[X] \rightarrow K := \psi_a(f) = f(a)$ is an homomorphism of an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that

> the application $\psi_a:F[X] \rightarrow K := \psi_a(f) = f(a)$ is an
>   homomorphism of an Integral Domain.

Def: I know that an Integral Domain is an abelian ring $A$ with $(a,b) \in A \rightarrow ab=0 \iff a=0$ or $b=0$.

edit: K is an extention of F

So I take $b=0 $ and define another application $\psi_b:F[X] \rightarrow K := \psi_b(g) = 0$.

$\psi_b(g)\psi_a(f)= (g)(0)(f)(a)$ because there is an application in this product that gives $0$, whatever value the other application could get.
You could also rearrange the $0$ and the $a$ to pass the value to the other function, and the claim still holds.

**I appreciate any edit/explanation/correction/suggestion because this is one of my first approach to abstract algebra.**

Thanks

Comment: For fixed $a\in F$, $\psi_a(fg)=f(a)g(a)$.

Comment: Is $F=K$ or at least $F \subseteq K$ ?

Comment: Yes, K  is an extention of F, edited

Comment: @YadatiKiran yes, this is a good version, is mine right or wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate what your understanding of a homomorphism of integral domains is? In particular why you are choosing some $b$?

Comment: @kesa I was thinking that taking another element of $F$ I could show that via product $\psi_b(g)\psi_a(f)$ there is a $0$ (the $b=0$ value in this case) that could be arranged to hold the definition of integral domain anyway, so that even in $K$, the arrival set of the application, is valid the definition of integral domain. I apologize to all if this is very wrong, it was an idea of mine to prove this.

Comment: Do you agree that a homomorphism of integral domains is just a usual ring homomorphism where both, source and target are integral domains?
This might cause some confusion..

Comment: Yes, this is right. It's an application that goes from an i.d. to another i.d.

Comment: Ok, then instead of chosing an element $b$ (probably from $K$), shouldn't you rather take two elements, $f,g$ from the target $F[X]$ and check, that $\psi_a(f+g) = \psi_a(f) + \psi_a(g)$ and similarly for multiplication (As Yadati Kiran suggested already)?

Comment: $f,g \in F[X]$ and $a \in K$, right? This is the easy way to show that the properties of homomorphism are valid between two i.d., so it's sufficient to show that it's valid for the target, because we know that $F$ is an extention of $K$ and i$K$ is an i.d., right?

Comment: Yes. The problem is to see that the above map defines a well-defined homomorphism at all, not that source and target are integral domains. This (although not mentioned explicitly) follows from the fact that fields are integral domains, and polynomial rings over integral domains are again integral domains. (you have a type in the last comment; $K$ is an extension of $F$)